# Better / Other way of selecting data in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

Imagine this example table of products

```
id | price | properties                                                    | description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------
1  | 22.9  | color=red, weigth=10, width=100                               | mountainbike
2  | 56.3  | shape=rectangle, weight=12, opaque=true                       | small toolbox
3  | 67    | shape=rectangle, weight=15, opaque=false, height=9, width=120 | big toolbox
```

the column "properties" is the cassandra collection type "map"

Okay, first: Why not using properties as own columns? Cause its not specified what properties the items will have, so this part ist dynamic.

What i want to know is, is there a performant way of selecting a specified item by its properties? Something like

```
SELECT price FROM products WHERE properties.color = red AND properties.weigth=10 AND properties.width=100
```

I want to match exactly one product which grants all properties that are requested.

So the following situation shouldnt be possible

```
id | price | properties                                                    | description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------
1  | 22.9  | color=red, weigth=10, width=100                               | mountainbike
9  | 56.3  | color=red, weigth=10, width=100                               | another mountainbike
```

So the properties column rather is the primary key, even if it looks strange that no other product can have the same properties.

How to do that?

I found a description where collections (in this case a map) in newer versions of cassandra can be secondary indexed, so its possible to use the WHERE-clause on in. But its not recommended to do that, because it dont scale out well and i dont know how many properties each product will have. Fact is, if there is a product which has exactly the requested properties it should be the only one.

Has anybody another idea to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense performance-wise to use an index (see [When to use and not use an index](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html)), consider using a User Defined Type. In 2.1.2, you use the frozen keyword. You cannot update parts of a user-defined type value. The entire value must be overwritten. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen, user-defined type like a blob.

```
    CREATE KEYSPACE abc_ks WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 };
    CREATE TYPE abc_ks.props (
      color text,
      weight text,
      width text,
      prop4 text,
      prop5 text,
      prop6 text,
      prop7 text
    );

    CREATE TABLE abc_ks.prod_line (
      id int,
      price double,
      description text,
      properties frozen<props>,
      PRIMARY KEY (description, id) 
    ); 

    INSERT INTO abc_ks.prod_line (id, price, description, properties) VALUES (1, 22.9, 'mountainbike', {color:'red', weight:'10', width:'100'});

    INSERT INTO abc_ks.prod_line (id, price, description, properties) VALUES (2, 122.5, 'mountainbike', {color:'blue', weight:'12', width:'90', prop4:'speed_12'});

    INSERT INTO abc_ks.prod_line (id, price, description, properties) VALUES (3, 90.5, 'small tool', {prop5:'shape_rectangle', weight:'15'});

    INSERT INTO abc_ks.prod_line (id, price, description, properties) VALUES (4, 100.6, 'mountainbike', {color:'blue', weight:'15', width:'90', prop4:'speed_12'});

    INSERT INTO abc_ks.prod_line (id, price, description, properties) VALUES (5, 106.5, 'mountainbike', {color:'blue', weight:'15', width:'90', prop4:'speed_12'});

    CREATE INDEX ON abc_ks.prod_line (properties);

    SELECT description, id FROM abc_ks.prod_line WHERE properties = {color: 'blue', weight:'15', width:'90', prop4:'speed_12'};

     description  | id
    --------------+----
     mountainbike |  4
     mountainbike |  5
```